# How to find a pattern in string using PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a text and I want to return the string until the first occurrence of  a pattern "not including the pattern"

Here is my text

```
Hello World,
I should see this and only this <br> test<br>
On Apr 29, 2015, at 11:50 AM, Blah &lt;<a href=
"mailto:blah@blah.com">blah@blah.com</a>&gt;
wrote:<br>
```

the pattern that I am looking for is something like this

```
On____<______>___ wrote:
```

Here is an example of the text

```
On Apr 29, 2015, at 11:50 AM, Blah &lt;<a href=
"mailto:blah@blah.com">blah@blah.com</a>&gt;
wrote:<br>
```

to find this patter tried this code

```
$pattern = '~On.*?<([^>]*)>\s+wrote:~';
$isWebApp = preg_match($pattern, $message, $matches);

if($isWebApp !== false && isset($matches[0]) ){
    $pos = strpos($message, $matches[0]);
    $message = substr($message, 0, $pos);
}
echo $message;
```

But it is not working.

my expected output is

```
Hello World,
    I should see this and only this <br> test<br>
```

How can I correct the pattern to make it find what I am looking for?

Comment: So you want everything until the first `<` ?

Comment: Do you ultimately want everything _before_ 'On'? Do you anticipate new lines to be a part of the String you are searching?

Comment: before 'On' or after 'On' ?

Comment: @PedroLobito Seems like everyone is lurking until the smoke clears :)

Comment: @Mike what is your expected output?

Comment: Use `strpos` to find the index and then use `substr`. You don't need to use `preg_match`.

Comment: my expected output is everything prior `On`

Comment: @Mike can you update your question with your literal expected output?

Comment: @Mike ok, thanks. You can take a look at the answers

Comment: You keep changing  your question, frustrating...sorry,  no more help.

Comment: @Mike your question is unclear and contradictory... I answered based in your expected output but not sure if you want that now

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
([\s\S]*?)On[\s\S]*?wrote
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/iB2iX7/3)**

Php code

```
$re = "/([\\s\\S]*?)On[\\s\\S]*?wrote/"; 
$str = "Hello World,\nI should see this and only this <br> test<br>\nOn Apr 29, 2015, at 11:50 AM, AccoRDI &lt;<a href=\n\"mailto:blah@blah.com\">blah@blah.com</a>&gt;\nwrote:<br>"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

Match information

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-59]  `Hello World,
I should see this and only this <br> test<br>
`
```

Btw, if you want to follow your pattern: `On____<______>___ wrote:`. You could use this regex:

```
([\s\S]*?)On[\s\S]*?<[\s\S]*?>[\s\S]*?wrote
```

Comment: there could be lots of `On` in the test so I will need to identify the pattern and return everything before it

Comment: @Mike fixed, let me know if the updates in the answer is what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = '
Hello World,
I should see this and only this <br> test<br>
On Apr 29, 2015, at 11:50 AM, Blah &lt;<a href=
"mailto:blah@blah.com">blah@blah.com</a>&gt;
wrote:<br>
';

    preg_match('/On(.*?)wrote/s',$x,$m);

    echo $m[1];
```

will output:

Apr 29, 2015, at 11:50 AM, Blah <blah@blah.com>